# C# Webservice error: Message security verification failed

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I am trying to consume an authetication Web Service passing in SOAP header with UsernameToken using custom binding

```
ICollection<BindingElement> bindingElements = new List<BindingElement>();
HttpsTransportBindingElement httpBindingElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
CustomTextMessageBindingElement textBindingElement = new CustomTextMessageBindingElement();
SecurityBindingElement securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;
bindingElements.Add(securityElement);
bindingElements.Add(textBindingElement);
bindingElements.Add(httpBindingElement);
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(bindingElements);

EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://....");

var client = new WebServiceClient(binding, address);
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "USERNAME HERE";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "PASSWORD HERE";

using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    var req = new WebServiceRequest();
    var resp = client.initiate(req);
}
```

getting an exception:

> Message security verification failed.
>
> Cannot read the token from the 'BinarySecurityToken' element with the
>   'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'
>   namespace for BinarySecretSecurityToken, with a 'oblix:ObSSOCookie'
>   ValueType. If this element is expected to be valid, ensure that
>   security is configured to consume tokens with the name, namespace and
>   value type specified."}

Server stack trace:

> at System.ServiceModel.Security.TransportSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message&
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessage(Message&
>   message, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[]
>   correlationStates)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message
>   reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

Here's the response caught by fiddler:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="oblix:ObSSOCookie" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:oblix="http://schemas.oblix.com/ws/2004/04/authentication"><!--REMOVED--></wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <MobileAppsLoginSSOProcessResponse  xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/MobileAppsLoginSSO">
            <ReturnStatus>SUCCESS</ReturnStatus>
        </MobileAppsLoginSSOProcessResponse>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I am using CustomTextMessageEncoder following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

**EDIT:**

As suggested by Yaron, unless I strip out the BinarySecurityToken tag from the response, the code fails with above Message Security Validation Failed exception.

The 'oblix:ObSSOCookie' in the response is authentication cookie sent by service back to client on successful authentication and I believe, client needs to save this cookie.

**Solution:**
As suggested by Yaron in final edit, I removed `SecurityElementBinding` from Custom Binding and used Custom Message Inspector (`IClientMessageInspector`) to inject Security tag into the header.

This allowed to interpret the response only from SOAP body and I can read the SOAP response header in `AfterReceiveReply` of my `IClientMessageInspector` implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server returns an x.509 token in the response and WCF is not sure what to do with it (this token is not expected in username auth). I see two options:

1. in your encoder strip out the security tag from the response

   OR
2. do not use security at all and in the encoder (or a message inspector if you prefer) push the user/pass headers to the request

EDIT: You say this token should be used by the client in further calls. I'm not sure what is the correct way to handle this so I'll give a quick way which will work (but feels a little patchy). Don't define any security at all (remove the security element from the binding). Then use a custom message inspector (or an encoder but it is harder) to push into the message the user/pass in the correct format (see how they are sent when security binding is used). this should not be hard. then WCF will not validate the token on response. you can user the same message inspector you already have in place to inspect the response and extract the token. your main class (which initialize the proxy) is also the class that initialized the inspector so it should have access to its data members in order to access the token and resend it.

it would have been so much easier if the server would send you the token inside the body and not header.
also there might be a way to do it in a non-patchy weay by implementing custom tokens / behaviors but in my mind this adds more abstraction and it is better to be concrete.

Comment: Response includes authentication token in the Security > BinarySecurityToken. I am not sure that it is of no use.

Comment: can you suggest some way to process the security tag without this exception?

Comment: ok, now I see that this is not a regular x.509 token but something called oblix:ObSSOCookie. This cookie is something WCF is not able to handle out of the box. Either you or the vendor know how to do it, in which case you should implement a WCF custom token, or you decide you do not care about it and remove it as suggested above. You need to discuss with the vendor what this cookie means and how you should handle / validate it. heres how to create custom tokens which is the correct approach,

Comment: I assume you could also do something more quick and dirtly like do the validation inside your method code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731872.aspx

Comment: Not sure I understand your suggestion of using Custom Tokens. I am able to send the Security header with UsernameToken to the service and in turn service authenticates the username correctly.
The only problem is that the BinarySecurityToken send by service back to the client is causing issues.
Are you suggesting to use custom token instead of the UsernameToken which client sends to the service?

Comment: no, I was suggesting to use a custom token to handle the custom token which comes back from the service. The question is what you want to do with that token. In general I rarely see that a server returns such a token to a client (for what - client already sent a message to the server, no point to authenticate now). Possibly you also want to ignore this token in which case no need of custom tokens but just remove it in an encoder. You need to understand what you are supposed to do with this token since it is not standard.

Comment: seems little clearer now, it is a cookie in the SOAP Response header which I need to capture and inject into consecutive requests.
Any thoughts on it?

Comment: The solution in last edit worked. I removed the SecurityBindingElement from custom binding and then injected Custom Message Inspector to add the security tag into the header.
However, I still need to figure out a way to save capture the cookie and use it in consecutive requests.